# Attaching data/object to a tab in tabbed layout

Tags: java, android, android-tablayout

I have created a tab Layout which creates a tab for every doctor object i have in a List. Currently i am setting the tab title as doctor name but when a tab is selected, I want to get the id of the corresponding doctor. I could get this from the position in the list but i am hoping there is a cleaner solution. Is there any way to attach an object or even just an id to a tab on creation so that i can access it directly from the selected tab when my listener is fired?

```
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("All"));
for(Doctors doctor: list)
{
    TabLayout.Tab tempTab = tabLayout.newTab().setText(doctor.getName());
    tempTab.setIcon(R.drawable.john_smith_photo);

    //here i would like to put doctor.getId() into my tab
    tabLayout.addTab(tempTab);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `setTag()` method? See [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(java.lang.Object)). You can use it in any class that extends View and you can store data with it. To retrieve the data, you can use `getTag()`. Also works for [TabLayout.Tab.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.Tab.html#setTag(java.lang.Object))

> Tags can also be used to store data within a view without resorting to another data structure.

It's as simple as:

```
tempTab.setTag(doctor.getId());
```

Comment: thanks for your solution. I thought that might work but i seen object as a param in the documentation. I guess that means you can put anything into it even the doctor object, is that correct?

Comment: I think so!! :)